# aligning div at center text-align not working

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want the circle to be aligned in center in 768 grid

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dEN3/1/)

### HTML

```
<div class="About_Container">
  <div class="Icon_Wrapper">
    <div class="Circle">
      <div class="CircleWrapper"> <span class="Icon"> 
   <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/drupal_50108/sites/default/files/icon-service-3.png" /> </span>
   <span class="Text"> CUSTOMER GUARANTEEE </span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Text_Wrapper"> Vestibulum quis felis ut enim aliquam iaculis.
    Nullam pharetra tortor at quam viverra volutpat. 
    Phasellus vel faucibus dolor. Curabitur ac ni
    i non metus dignissim dapibus eu vel nibh. Phasellus </div>
  <div class="Link_Wrapper"> <a href="#">READ MORE</a> </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
@media ( min-width: 120px) and (max-width:768px) {

#Container_About {
    min-height: 1291px;
    background: #404040;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.TradeSlogan {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 66px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.SomeTextWrapper {
    color: #949393;
    margin: 10px;
}

.SomeTextWrapper  .SomeTextWrapper:before,  .SomeTextWrapper:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.SomeTextWrapper:after { clear: both; }

/**
     * For IE 6/7 only
     * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
     */

.SomeTextWrapper {  *zoom: 1;
}

.About_Container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.Circle {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 170px;
    width: 170px;
    border-radius: 170px;
    background: #949393;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.Icon_Wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.CircleWrapper { padding: 10px; }

.CircleWrapper Icon, Text {
    float: left;
    height: 44%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 3%;
}

.Text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #03c7de;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.Text_Wrapper {
    margin: 25px;
    color: #03c7de;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.Link_Wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

.Link_Wrapper a {
    color: #03c7de;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
```

Comment: but where is the circle?

Comment: Did you check the fiddle in fiddle please reduce the output screen size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Icon_Wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 170px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Since We know the width of the circle We can make the Container `(.Icon_Wrapper)` of the  circle to have its width and align it to the center of the page via `margin:auto`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dEN3/9/)

Comment: Can you explain why margin is given auto

Comment: @user3127499 The `margin:auto` is used so that you can set the left and right margins to auto to horizontally center that element within its container.

Comment: Does margin auto works only if the width is given and can you explain what does margin:auto auto and margin:10px auto and margin:auto; difference is

Comment: @AlexThomas Thanks for clarifying him i was little busy with my work :)

Answer (score 2):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/8dEN3/5/

```
.Circle{

        margin:10px auto;
        height:170px;
        width:170px;
        border-radius:170px;
        background:#949393;
        display:block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why margin is given auto

Comment: margin auto is for give available equal margin from both side.

Comment: The text in the circle isn't middle aligned

Comment: +1 for the answer @AlexThomas yep thats why it was not accepted as answer width: 170px;
  margin: auto;   was the simplest solution to answer thats kawaneesh answer was accepted as answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.Circle{
    margin:auto;
    height:170px;
    width:170px;
    border-radius:170px;
    background:#949393;
    text-align:center;
}

.Circle .CircleWrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 170px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Mcc/1/

Comment: check your fiddle its still aligned to left